# Backpack and Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm starting with Laravel 8 and have installed jetstream and inertia.
I would like to have and admin panel using backpack and a client access. My problem is when a user tries to login with inertia form, after successful validation then backpack login form appears.
It seems (if I'm not wrong), the issue is with path. Inertia is loading /dashboard route and backpack uses admin/dashboard and I think middleware is interfering. Is there any possibility to change dashboard path?
Has anybody faced this problem?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you showed us the related configurations for both packages and their login controllers. Off the top of my head, Id check `route_prefix` in `config/backpack/base.php`, does this say 'admin'? If it does, is your other package also trying to use the "admin/dashboard" route? If Thats the case and you want to prevent that, you could set `setup_auth_routes`, `setup_dashboard_routes`, and `setup_my_account_routes` to false  and create your own routes in `routes/backpack/custom.php` using `vendor/backpack/crud/src/routes/backpack/base.php` as a guide.

Comment: Thankyou @WesleySmith, thats what I needed